# Question about browser sessions

Tags: session, browser, struts

In a java web app, if I am browsing a site and then I open another IE 8 window* and go to the same site, is there a way to detect that the new request has come from another window from the same machine.

Basically my requirement is to alert the user that they cannot open another window with the same site.

*In IE 8 all windows share the same session. Hence request.getsession() would always return the same ID across all the windows.

Comment: While this is not an answer to your question, be aware that IE >=8 has a "New Session" feature which allows to run independent sessions in multiple windows: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2009/05/06/session-cookies-sessionstorage-and-ie8.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

There is a great article about this exact question over at [The Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/MultipleTabWindows.aspx). It's not 100% possible to detect this, but it is possible to work around it.